# Import font with just HTML no CSS or link tags

Tags: html, fonts

I am using slides.com for my portfolio and was using the style tag for the font raleway which is installed on my computer.

Unfortunately I didn't realize that the font wouldn't be installed on other people's computers and so now the presentation will come out ugly on the recruiters browser.

So I need a way to import the font with just html tags because slides.com doesn't allow css or link tags -__-

Comment: How is that off topic? You simply have to answer that it currently isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `@font-face` property:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: raleway;
    src: url(raleway.ttf);
}
```

Then apply it to your element:

```
.slides
{
   font-family: raleway;
}
```

The only other way to do it is to tell your clients to download and install the raleway font, which is atrocious design.